# Conditional Probability of Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

I am currently studying the Poisson distribution, and I am wondering whether the following calculation is possible:

Let $X$ represent the number of people who visit the airport in 1 hour and let $X$ follow a Poisson distribution with a mean of $10$.

Given that 5 people have visited the airport in the first 30 minutes, what is the probability of an additional 10 or more people visiting in the remaining hour?

Comment: This is not precise enough.  Did you mean given that 5 people have visited (entered?) the airport in 30 minutes, what is the probability of 10 or more in the **next** hour, or **remainder** of the hour (next 30 minutes)? Also, welcome to the site; you should try to explain how you have approached the question and not just pose it.

Comment: I meant the remainder of the hour. I was trying to solve it using conditional probability. Since 5 people already visited the airport in the first 30 minutes, let's denote this as X >= 5 and I attempted to calculate P(X >= 15 | X >= 5). Is it appropriate approach? btw thank you for welcoming me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson process is based on independent events with a constant (mean) rate per unit of time and is "memoryless".  This means that if the process has mean 10 per hour, it has mean 5 per half hour. So you are really just looking for $P(\geq 10)$ from a Poisson distribution with mean 5.

Comment: This is really no different than a much simpler example.  Given that "Red" has come up 10 consecutive times in Roulette, what is the probability of "Black" on the next spin? It's 18/38, the "history" does not matter.  Same as die or coin-toss problems.  Conditional probability and independence can easily play tricks on you!